# How to check if one array contains another in php in a sequence?

Tags: php, indexing, contains

I have two arrays:

```
$a = array("w","c","d","e","g","h");
$b = array("c","d","e");
$c = array("c","e","d");
```

It should return "TRUE" if we check if $a contain $b or $a contain $c because the index of $b are in sequence with $a & $c i.e.they all have  $ "c","d","e" and they come in a sequence in $a.
However, if `$b = array("c", "g", "d")`, then we should get false because it has all the elements but they are not in correct sequence in $a.

Comment: Tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$a = ["w","c","d","e","g","h"];
$b = ["c","d","e"];
$c = ["c","e","d"];
function containsSequence($arr, $subArray){
    $keys = array_keys($arr, $subArray[array_keys($subArray)[0]]); 
    foreach($keys as $k) {
        if(array_slice($arr, $k, count($subArray)) == $subArray){
            return true;    
        }
    }
    return false;
}
echo 'Contains sequence: '.(containsSequence($a,$b)?'yes:':'no');
echo 'Contains sequence: '.(containsSequence($a,$c)?'ues':'no');
```